# How to calculate hazard ratio with coxph output

Tags: r, statistics, cox-regression, cox

I have successfully got summary output from 'coxph'. However, now I am curious how to get the hazard ratio from these numbers? Is there a calculation I can do with what I have, or is there a certain code in R that will produce what I want?[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOYhW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hazard ratio is [represented](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/what-is-the-difference-between-the-coef-and-expcoef-output-of-coxph-in-r) by the `exp(coef)` column of the `coxph()` output.

For each treatment group, `exp(coef)` gives the hazard against whatever you're using as the control or baseline group.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That makes sense, but now I am confused why my exp(coef) numbers are so big...? The hazard ratios don't seem right.

Comment: You're welcome.  Re large ratios, might be a better question for CrossValidated.  You can start [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32225/cox-proportional-hazard-model-and-interpretation-of-coefficients-when-higher-cas?rq=1)...